# Trouble changing a CALayer's "contents" property to captured photo

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, avfoundation, calayer

I am using AV Foundation and have created a main layer and a sub layer. The main layer displays a live "preview" of what the camera sees before the user takes a photo. After the user takes a photo, I want to set the value of the sublayer's contents property to the captured photo. Everything works perfectly, except for setting the contents of the sublayer.

And I know the sublayer is working because I am able to give it a background color of blue and when I take a photo in the app it will successfully turn the sublayer blue.

Here is my code where I am trying to set the sublayer to be the captured image:

```
NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageDataSampleBuffer];


UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imageData];


CALayer *subLayer = [CALayer layer];


subLayer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];


subLayer.frame = _previewLayer.frame;


[_previewLayer addSublayer:subLayer];
```

I have tried several different ways of setting the sublayer's contents property like these, but none of them work:

```
subLayer.contents = (id) [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

subLayer.contents = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

subLayer.contents = image;
```

Also, I know the sublayer is setup properly because if I add this statement it will turn the sublayer completely blue when I take a photo: 
`subLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;`

Any ideas how I can update the sublayer and make it display the photo that is being captured?

Answer (score 0):

On a whim I tried adding .CGImage to the imageWithData method call and it is now working. I sure wish it had that listed as a requirement in the xcode documentation.